# django ALLOWED_HOSTS not working

Tags: python, django, apache

My settings.py file contains:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [u'mydomainxxx.com']
```

Howevever, I'm able to fire a curl request like this: `curl -X GET https://mydomainxxx.com/api/ -H 'Authorization: Token some token'` and am getting the response.

I was hoping that using `ALLOWED_HOSTS` will prevent commands like curl to get response from my API.
Is this a normal behaviour ?

Comment: You have debug turned on?

Comment: As mentioned above, it is False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for anyone who would like to filter on referer url and not on ip address, we can use the following middleware:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django import http

class AllowHostsMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        referer_url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','')
        if referer_url.startswith(settings.ALLOWED_REFERER_URL):
            return None
        return http.HttpResponseForbidden('<h1>Forbidden</h1>')
```

Answer (score 6):

You are confusing the [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) setting with something else. It denotes the hostnames that your server will listen to; not the hostnames of connecting hosts. There is no built in method to prevent it but you can easily write a middleware to check connecting hostnames.

Your current setting will prevent this from getting a response:

```
curl -X GET http://another_domainxxx.com/api/ -H 'Authorization: Token some token'
```

even if both `mydomainxxx.com` and `another_domainxxx.com` will resolve to the same IP Address.

Comment: Thanks Selcuk, can you please point me to a good resource from where I can write this middleware ?

Comment: @SaurabhVerma If you want to restrict by IP address, you can try https://github.com/muccg/django-iprestrict/ or modify it to restrict according to hostname.

Comment: Thanks, I've added my answer also, which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add your domain or ip to the **Allowed_Hosts**
and then type the following command

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

then

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn and
```