# Django Rest + React: how to restrict domain origin of requests

Tags: django, reactjs, security, django-rest-framework, axios

I am currently building a web application.

- My **front-end** is developed using **React** and Axios (for API call requests).
  It is served directly by Nginx on **app.mydomain.com**
- My **back-end** is developed using Django and **Django Rest**.
  It is served with Nginx and Gunicorn on **api.mydomain.com**. It only serves API endpoints.

So the front-end and the back-end are separated.

I would like **only my front-end (app.mydomain.com)** to be able **to make API requests to my Django Rest backend**.

I would like to **prevent any other domain**, any clients such as postman, insomnia, curl or any script **to make API requests to my backend**.

I have already set CORS in Django Rest. However, I can still make requests to the backend using curl or any other client.

Do you have any idea of what I could do to achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance for you answers.

Comment: This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600443/django-allowed-hosts-not-working/35616168#35616168

Comment: @MamdouhAlsarayreh Perfect, that works! Thanks a lot. Just wondering, is this solution secure? Am I sure nobody will be able to modify the HTTP_REFERER header? Are there other things to take into account? Thanks.

Comment: Ever find the answer to this? I can't wrap my head around this exact question.

Answer (score 0):

steps :

1.`python -m pip install django-cors-headers`

2.`INSTALLED_APPS = [ ..., "corsheaders", ..., ] #add it to your installed apps:`

3.#add a middleware class to listen in on responses,

`MIDDLEWARE = [ ..., "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware", "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware", ...,  ]`

4.`CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [ "https://api.mydomain.com", ]`

**That's it!**

Comment: This will not work. CORS policy is only enforced by Web Browsers, not by API clients like Postman.